# gnuplot how to put legend/Key in third column with multiplot

Tags: gnuplot

How do I put legend/Key outside of my plots in the third column (here) ?

The name of my labels are stored in the Countries's name list. So the 4 curves in each graph correspond to a country.

You can find the data here : https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/en/publications-data/data-national-14-day-notification-rate-covid-19

Data look likes this :

```
France,FRA,Europe,67012883,cases,1,2020-07,0.00895350226910846,12,"Epidemic intelligence, national weekly data"
France,FRA,Europe,67012883,cases,0,2020-08,0.00149225037818474,12,"Epidemic intelligence, national weekly data"
France,FRA,Europe,67012883,cases,118,2020-09,0.1760855446258,130,"Epidemic intelligence, national weekly data"
France,FRA,Europe,67012883,cases,996,2020-10,1.66236692129781,1126,"Epidemic intelligence, national weekly data"
```

my script :

```
#system("wgets https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath/csv -P $PWD -O data1.csv")
Countries = "France Italy Belgium Luxembourg"
categories = "cases death"

reset
set term wxt font ',11' size 1200,800
set datafile separator ","
set grid
set key outside right top

timefmt = "%Y-%W"
set xtics time format timefmt rotate by -45
SECPERWEEK = 3600.*24.*7.
Y_W(col) = timecolumn(col,timefmt) + SECPERWEEK * (strcol(col)[6:7] - 1)

set multiplot layout 3,3
do for [category in categories]{
    set title sprintf("Nbre %s",category)
    plot for [country in Countries] sprintf("<grep %s.*%s data1.csv",country,category) u (Y_W(7)):6 notitle w l lw 2
}

#PUT legend
set multiplot next

#t sprintf("Nbre %s %s",category,country)

do for [category in categories]{
    set title sprintf("%s %s","%",category)
    plot for [country in Countries] sprintf("<grep %s.*%s data1.csv",country,category) u (Y_W(7)):8 notitle w l lw 2
}
set multiplot next
#sprintf("%s %s %s","%",category,country)

do for [category in categories]{
    set title sprintf("Cumul %s",category)
    plot for [country in Countries] sprintf("<grep %s.*%s data1.csv",country,category) u (Y_W(7)):9 notitle w l lw 2
}
set multiplot next
#t sprintf("Cumul %s %s",category,country)

unset multiplot
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible suggestion: use screen coordinates for the key and show the title only for one graph. Something like this:

**Code:** (edit: simply `unset key` after the first plot)

```
### only one key for multiplot
reset session

Countries = "France Italy Belgium Luxembourg"

set key at screen 0.9, 0.9
set multiplot layout 3,3 columnsfirst
    do for [i=1:6] {
        plot for [j=1:words(Countries)] j*x**i ti word(Countries,j)
        unset key
    }
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

When plotting the key several times on top of each other, e.g. in a wxt terminal, it might look like bold (probably depends on the terminal). See example below. Top row: 6 keys on top of each other, Bottom row: only one key. So it might be better to turn off key after the first plot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have missed the screen option for key. Don't need to put a if condition on mytitle because the label will be print twice at the same position. set key at screen 0.9, 0.9 and plot .... t sprintf("%s",country) are enough

Comment: @Suntory well, plotting twice on top of each other might lead to slightly different results, i.e. it will look bold (probably depends on the terminal). But right, there is an easier way: simply `unset key` after the first plot.